# How can I connect 2 computers using sockets in Python?

Tags: python

I have been trying to connect 2 PCs, using sockets in Python, but the client does not connect to the server, the 2 computers are on the same network, but it does not allow me to make the connection. The codes are:

```
#Server

#Socket TCP
import socket
import os

#Criando o socket
host=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port=7000
BUFFER_SIZE=1024

print("Servidor a la escucha por el puerto: ",port, " en la direccion: ",host)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as socketTCP:
    socketTCP.bind((host,port)) #dar nombre al socket
    socketTCP.listen() #numero de conexiones simultaneas
    conn, addr = socketTCP.accept() #aceptar conexion
    
    with conn: #conectado
        print('Se ha conectado un cliente con datos:', addr)
        comando="Quieres usar algun comando: "
        conn.send(comando.encode('utf-8')) #enviar mensaje
        data1 = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) #recibir mensaje
        if(data1.decode('utf-8')=="no"): #si no quiere usar comandos
            while True: 
                data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) #recibir mensaje
                if(data.decode('utf-8')=="exit"): #si el mensaje es exit
                    print("Conexion terminada") #terminar conexion
                    socketTCP.close() #cerrar socket
                if not data: #si no hay datos
                    break #terminar conexion
                if(data.decode('utf-8')!="exit"): #si el mensaje no es exit
                    print("El cliente dice:",data.decode('utf-8')) #imprimir mensaje
                conn.send(data) #enviar mensaje
        if(data1.decode('utf-8')=="si"): #si quiere usar comandos
                archivo=conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) #recibir mensaje
                print("Quieres descargar el archivo: ",archivo.decode('utf-8')) #imprimir mensaje
                archivo=archivo.decode('utf-8') #convertir a string
                f = open(archivo, "rb") #abrir archivo
                tamano=os.path.getsize(archivo) #obtener tamaño del archivo
                if(f):
                    print("El archivo ",archivo," existe, vamos a enviarlo")
                    l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                    while (l):
                        conn.sendall(l)
                        l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                    print("Archivo enviado con exito de ",tamano," bytes")
                    f.close()
```

```
import socket

host=socket.gethostname()
port=12345
BUFFER_SIZE=1024
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as socketTCP:
    socketTCP.connect((host,port))
    data = socketTCP.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
    comando=input()
    socketTCP.send(comando.encode('utf-8'))
    if(comando=="no"):
        while(data.decode('utf-8')!="exit"):
            print("Ingresa el mensaje a enviar: ")
            MSG=input()
            socketTCP.send(MSG.encode('utf-8'))
            data = socketTCP.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if(comando=="si"):
            print("Quieres descargar algo, ingresa el nombre")
            archivo=input()
            socketTCP.send(archivo.encode('utf-8'))
            archivo2="Copia-"+archivo
            f = open(archivo2, "wb")
            l = socketTCP.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            while (l):
                f.write(l)
                print("Recibiendo archivo... con caracteres como: ",l.hex())
                l = socketTCP.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            print("Archivo recibido con exito")
            f.close()
```

Try to enter the ip of the server computer, the localhost, disable Firewall, and nothing works. (I am executing them in Windows and at the moment of executing it tells me that the server takes a long time to respond)

Comment: Have you tried debugging with REALLY simple code first? To see if the connection can even be sent/received?

Comment: The client machine is trying to connect to *itself*, rather than the machine that the server is running on.  But note that running both ends on the same machine is a reasonable thing to do for initial testing; it avoids all sorts of potential issues involving firewalls, private vs. public IP addresses, etc.

Comment: what is gethostbyname returning?

Comment: Yes, in this code the client is connecting on the same machine, but I have tried to enter another hostname address in the client and the IP address of the server, but it still does not work.

Comment: And yes, I have been trying with simple codes, but it cannot connect, I also tried on Linux, this due to the Firewall problems they had on Windows, but the connection still does not work.

Comment: What getbyhostname returns to me is the ip address of the host name, that is, the server.